# Openlayers 3 - limit possible zoom levels on the map

Tags: zooming, openlayers-3

I need to keep the zoom level between certain levels (5-19) and not allow the user to zoom in/out any further. I've tried setting the minZoom/maxZoom properties of the view, and also the minResolution/maxResolution, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code:

```
map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM( {crossOrigin: null} )
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: ({
            collapsible: false
        })
    }),
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 5,
        minZoom: 5,
        maxZoom: 19,
        minResolution: 4891.96981025128,
        maxResolution: 39135.75848201024,
        projection: new ol.proj.get("EPSG:900913")
    })
});
```

I've tried it using just the settings for minZoom/maxZoom, just the ones for minResolution/maxResolution or all of them... nothing happens, I am stil able to zoom further.

Edit: it was "zoom: 5", not "zoom: 2" in the code above.

Comment: Don't use both: `maxZoom`, `minResolution`, read the [docs](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.View.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 5,
    minZoom: 5,
    maxZoom: 19,
    minResolution: 4891.96981025128,
    maxResolution: 39135.75848201024,
    projection: new ol.proj.get("EPSG:900913")
})
```

Change zoom parameter to 5 or more. It will fix your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I've changed it by mistake, but I checked and it was zoom: 5 in the original code. It still doesn't work.

Comment: check your zoom level in console after the page load, using following syntax map.getView().getZoom()

Comment: I've checked it, it says 5.

Comment: now zoom out till the level it can and then check the zoom value in console. You have no need to mention min and max resolution parameter.

Comment: So, the default value when it loads is 5, and after each click on the zoom-out button it decreases by 1, until 0. The same thing happens when I zoom in, it keeps increasing after it reaches 19.

Comment: check this example http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/zoom-constrained.html

Comment: Hmm... so I've looked at the differences between the code in the example and mine, and for some reason, removing the "controls" property when defining the map seems to do the trick, even though it was just the default controls. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

try to add **maxResolution** property to ol.view in map element.

```
`  view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.transform([20.6031834, 48.6325657], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            zoom: 11,
            maxResolution: 4000

        })`
```

Easy map example

```
 var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [map, satMap],
        target: 'map',
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions: ({
                collapsible: false
            })
        }),
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.transform([20.6031834, 48.6325657], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            zoom: 11,
            maxResolution: 4000

        })
    });
```